# Enabling SSL on spring boot reactive web application and making a http call to that printing an exception noise in console

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

After I made the my spring boot reactive web application to support SSL, when I try to make a http call to the server, it prints below exception trace in console. As an application owner I cannot prevent any one hitting my service. But I should be able to prevent that trace printing in console, especially in a reactive web app, <s>where an IO operation is costly</s> . Any idea to prevent this ?

**Edit 3** :

```
2018-10-01 14:11:18.440 ERROR 12457 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.i.n.channel.CloseableContextHandler    : Handler failure while no child channelOperation was present
```

**Edit 2**:

<s>where an IO operation is costly</s> I just realized that this might be happening outside event loop thread pool. So it may not block any threads. But I still like to prevent that from printing in console.

**Edit 1** :

#### Steps to reproduce

- Checkout the project https://github.com/sp13ceg/spring-boot-reative-ssl
- start the server
  `./gradlew booRun`
- Make a insecure https call `curl --insecure https://localhost:8080/hi` works without error
- Make a http call `curl http://localhost:8080/hi` you will see the exception in console.

  io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 474554202f686920485454502f312e310d0a486f73743a206c6f63616c686f73743a383434340d0a557365722d4167656e743a206375726c2f372e35342e300d0a4163636570743a202a2f2a0d0a0d0a
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1178) [netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243) [netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489) [netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428) [netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:563) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) [netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: can you share configuration file for your app ?

Comment: server.port=8444
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=serverCerts/server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.client-auth=WANT
server.ssl.trust-store=serverCerts/ca.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password

Comment: Can you edit your question to add that information? How are you triggering this exception message?

Comment: I have edited the question with a link to sample project.

Answer (score 0):

I just missed an important thing in log trace. There was a line before the original stack trace which shows the name of the log from where it is coming. see **Edit 3**.

Adding this property disables this log getting printed in console.
`logging.level.reactor.ipc.netty.channel.CloseableContextHandler=off`